# Faster way to run grep on a large file

Tags: unix, foreach, grep, tcsh

I am running a foreach grep (4M lines) on couple of files with 4M+ lines. Is there a faster way for me to run this? I am on tcsh.

```
foreach f ( `cat strings` )

set var1 = `fgrep "$f" 1.rpt | awkk 2` 

set var2 = `fgrep "$f" 1.rpt | awkk 3` 

set var3 = `fgrep "$f" 2.rpt | awkk 2` 

set var4 = `fgrep "$f" 2.rpt | awkk 3` 

echo "$f | $var1 | $var2 | $var3 | $var4" >> output.rpt &

end
```

Comment: Use temporary files instead of doing same grep two times!

Comment: Don't use a shell loop, just use a single awk command instead and it'll run orders of magnitude faster. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for why. Also don't write scripts in [t]csh ([google CSH Why Not](https://www.google.com/search?q=CSH+Why+Not&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1)). Without sample input, expected output and without knowing what `awkk` does, we can't provide more of an answer than that. See [ask] and try again if you'd like help.